# How to divide list into k sublists with approximately same values?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, sublist

I would like to divide a list into `k` sublists each having approx same response value.

I have lists of the form:

```
L = [[1,2,3,2], [4,5,2,2], [2,3,9,1], [5,7,2,1], [2,3,3,1]]
```

The response value is the last element of each sublist. Here, the response value has the range [1,2]

If k = 2, then the two sublists with approx equal response are A and B:

```
A = [[1,2,3,2], [2,3,3,1]                 # it has response values 1,2
B = [[2,3,9,1], [4,5,2,2], [5,7,2,1]]     # it has response values 1,2,1
```

The only thing that came in my mind was to use sorting somehow. But, there may be some pythonic way of doing it. Since, the list L can be very long say 10000, I expect an efficient way of doing it.

Comment: What is wrong with the *sorting* algorithm you used?  Maybe show it to us.

Comment: @thefourtheye k is the number of sublists that I have to form by dividing the list L.

Comment: @Codingman should the sublists be roughly the same length? What tolerance do you have on "approximately equal"? And what have you written so far?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Suppose, L has length = 13, then for k=3 each newly created sublist will have length/3 elements except that the last sublist will have length/3 + length%3 number of elements

Comment: @Codingman and is the fact that your example output is in the same order as your example input just a coincidence? If so, that is not a great example.

Comment: @jonrsharpe My bad. It was just a coincidence. Updated!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "each having approx the same response value" means? Do you want the sum of the response values to be the same, or do you want the response values within a list to be close to each other? Can you give an example with more sublists and more different response values? For instance, how would you want the values `[1,1,1,2,2,10]` to be divided into three sublists? Do you want `[1,1], [1,2], [2,10]` (values closest to each other) or `[1,2], [1,2], [1,10]` (closest sums) or something else (`[2,1], [2,1,1], [10]` (closest sums without regard to list length))?

Answer (score 0):

The method you explained is indeed one of the most pythonic/efficient. Sort the list by the response value and then split the sorted list into sublists by getting every `k`'th element:

```
def divideintokapprox(mylist, k):
    sortedlist = sorted(mylist, key=lambda x: -x[-1])
    return [sortedlist[i::k] for i in range(k)]
```

Example use:

```
L = [[1,2,3,2], [4,5,2,2], [2,3,9,1], [5,7,2,1], [2,3,3,1]]

sublists = divideintokapprox(L, 2)
print(sublists[0])
#[[1, 2, 3, 2], [2, 3, 9, 1], [2, 3, 3, 1]]
print(sublists[1])
#[[4, 5, 2, 2], [5, 7, 2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what the OP wants but I can show sorting a list of lists with 100,000 elements (*ie.* 100,000 sub-lists) takes only 230 msec on a slow Atom machine.  I hope the OP thinks it's "efficient" enough.

```
>>> x = [ [ random.randrange(100) for _ in xrange(random.randrange(1, 1000)) ] for _ in xrange(10**5) ]

>>> import time
>>> a=time.time(); x.sort(key=lambda sl: sl[-1]); b=time.time()
>>> 1e3*(b-a)
226.77206993103027

$ python -V
Python 2.7.8
$ head -10 /proc/cpuinfo 
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 28
model name      : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU D510   @ 1.66GHz
stepping        : 10
microcode       : 0x107
cpu MHz         : 1662.623
cache size      : 512 KB
physical id     : 0
```